# What are the long-term implications of converting archived SQL records into a normalized structure?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, optimization, normalization

The situation I have is that I have tables for `User` and `Product`, with a format akin to this:

**users**

- id (primary, integer)
- name
- vote_count (Integer)
- updated_at

**products**

- id (primary, integer)
- name
- price (Float)
- quantity (Integer)
- updated_at

The app only contains the aggregate counts, thus I'm not building a "votes" table or a "product_items" table, ergo, the `quantity` and `vote_count` columns.

I'm also keeping historical snapshots of each of these models, similar to the `paper_trail` gem of Ruby:

**versions**

- item_type
- item_id
- created_at
- object (text/blob)

Every day, a snapshot of each user and product is saved, and the data is stored as a simple blob inside `versions`.

Now, for a front-facing app and/or report, I want to do things like chart a product's price and quantity, changing over time. With the `versions` table, I simply extract all of the entries with the corresponding id/type and then, in the application code, deal with the `object` blob...i.e. convert each `object` into a `Hash` and extract the `price` and `quantity` fields.

OK, so assume that the `users` and `products` tables will have an arbitrary number of numerical fields that I want to track. The `versions` way of archiving records seems to become inefficient. If I wanted to extract a system-wide product price average over time `(SELECT AVERAGE(price) FROM PRODUCTS [join versions, extract price from :object, etc.] GROUP BY updated_at)`...I'm doing a query just to get the blob and then to calculate the average in application code.

(pretend I'm not using Postgres or otherwise using a HStore like system)

For consistency and performance sake, I'm contemplating normalizing the data encapsulated from `versions.objects`, into something like:

**archived_attributes**

- id
- name

e.g.

```
  {id: 1, name: quantity}, {id: 2, name: price}
```

**archived_values**

- item_id
- item_type
- archived_attribute_id (integer)
- value (float)
- created_at

  {item_id: 1, item_type: product, archived_attribute_id: 2, value: 10.5, created_at: 2012-10-10}

  {item_id: 2, item_type: product, archived_attribute_id: 2, value: 14.5, created_at: 2012-11-05}

I understand this takes some application logic up-front to manage, but what are the medium-term concerns that I might run into? Let's say the number of types of archived_attributes and records will arbitrarily grow, and even the frequency of snapshots, to the point where I could easily have a billion `archived_values` in a year. Am I right in assuming that even from 1B to 10B, the relative narrowness of this table will be manaegable for a reasonable MYSQL server?

Comment: To my opinion, a better way in this situation is to create mirror tables for archiving users and products.

Comment: I like that idea too, as it would certainly deal with the issue of converting the denormalized text into usable Objects. However -- and this is likely premature optimization -- what I'm trying to archive is just numerical values, and holding onto all the snapshots would also save records that I don't need (though obviously I could write logic to excise those fields).

Comment: Another option is to add columns for attributes that you need special processing into versions table. For example: you can add product_price and product_quantity. This will be simpler to implement and give better performance.

Comment: Your solution is not premature optimization at all because it will not give good performance. To my humble opinion, it is premature generalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think even if a high-level abstraction could be created that would seamlessly save and retrieve the attributes for the needed aggregations, it would eventually become unwieldy enough to outweigh whatever (minimal) optimization benefits might come out of it.

Stupid me, this is bringing in the Entity-Attribute-Value (name-value pairs) pattern, which has a boat-load of problems at the SQL level. As the SQL Antipatterns book says: "This appears to be an improved design. However, the simple database struc- ture doesn’t make up for the difficulty of using it."